# iteration Loop inside a cursor not working as expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

please help. The query below is not working as expected. It is expected to stop inserting when @count=1 but it doesn't stop. i can't figure out what the problem is , please help me out.

```
create procedure mypro
as

declare @count int
declare aa cursor

for select SerialNumb from FORMTABLE

  open aa

      declare @SerialNumb varchar(11)
      fetch next from aa into @SerialNumb

      while(@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
       begin
          if(@@FETCH_STATUS <>-2)
          select @count= COUNT(SerialNumb) from CARDTABLE where SerialNumb=@SerialNumb
          while (@count<>1)
           begin

     ---- variables declaration

          declare @name
          declare @location
          declare @status


         select  @name = name, @location = location, @status=status

         from FORMTABLE  where SerialNumb = @SerialNumb


        insert into FORMTABLE values(@name, @location, @status)


        set @count = @count-1
      end
        fetch next from aa into @SerialNumb
          end

close aa

deallocate aa
```

See sample data below:

```
DECLARE @FormTable TABLE
(
Serialnumb INT,
[GROUP] CHAR(1),
CLASS VARCHAR(50) 
)

INSERT INTO @FormTable
SELECT 400,'A','Science' UNION ALL 
SELECT 401,'B','Social science' UNION ALL 
SELECT 402,'C','philosophy' UNION ALL 
SELECT 403,'D','Engineering'
```

**CardTable**

```
 DECLARE @CardTable TABLE
(
Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Serialnumb INT,
Name VARCHAR(50) 
)

INSERT INTO @CardTable
SELECT 1,400,'Charey' UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,400,'Mike' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,400,'James' UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,401,'Vina' UNION ALL 
SELECT 5,400,'Gloria' UNION ALL 
SELECT 6,401,'Faith' UNION ALL 
SELECT 7,401,'Sarah' UNION ALL 
SELECT 8,402,'Joy' UNION ALL 
SELECT 9,402,'Rita'
```

The desired result should be:

**@FormTable**

```
Serialno    Group       Class
400     A       Science
401     B       Social science
402     C       philosophy
403     D       Engineering
400     A       Science
400     A       Science
400     A       Science
401     B       Social science
401     B       Social science
402     C       philosophy
```

Comment: From a first glance this looks like something you probably don't need a cursor for. Can you describe what it is intended to do?

Comment: @Martin, it is meant to COUNT(SerialNumb) from CARDTABLE , while @count<> 1,  insert into FORMTABLE  but it keeps inserting over and over again.

Comment: I see you've added some example data for the 2 tables. Now what is your cursor trying to do based on that data?

Comment: The cusor gets the serialnumb from the Formtable. if @count <> 1, duplicate rows in the Formtable. But my problem is it keeps duplicating even when @count=1

Comment: The desired result looks like a simple join between your starting tables. `select ft.Serialnumb, ft.[GROUP], ft.Class from FormTable ft join CardTable ct ON ft.Serialnumb = ct.Serialnumb` but I'm not sure why you would then want to store that result back in the original table.

Comment: i want the count for each serialnumb in both tables to be the same     @Martin

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with Martin, it seems you don't need cursor at all. A simple join would be suffice.

Why do you want to store data in your Form Table again?

Comment: i want the count for each serialnumb in both tables to be the same @Nil

Comment: Could you try the query provided by Martin, I think that's all you need.